# Network services not compatible after update

Tags: networking, update-manager

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop and recently brought my software up-to-date (through Update Manager).  Since the update, I can't use any of network services. During boot-up it shows messages like "waiting for network configuration" and "booting without network configuration", even though my Ethernet cable is plugged in. On the right upper corner, the icon for network connections doesn't exist anymore, so there's no WiFi either. Should I simply reinstall Ubuntu or is there some other way?

Note: My laptop is dual-booted, and everything runs fine in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Network not starting after update. Some Ubuntu systems do not work any more after the latest Kernel update to 3.2.0-60-generic, especially the Network interface. Here is how to fix this:

```
sudo dkms remove e1000e/2.5.4 –k 3.2.0-60-generic
sudo dkms build e1000e/2.5.4 –k 3.2.0-60-generic
sudo dkms install e1000e/2.5.4 –k 3.2.0-60-generic
sudo modprobe e1000e
```